# Update nth array value under embedded documents in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, embedded-documents

I want to update only the nth position in that array, Instead of updating all the values in the array.
`db.patient.insertMany([
{firstName: "Thanga",lastName:"Durai",  age:27,history:{disease:["Cold","ulergy"]}}]);`

Here, Can you please tell me how to update value "Cold" into "Fever", remains are the same.

I already know another method to archive this, but using this I have to update all the values in an array: 
`db.patient.updateOne({firstName:"Thanga","history.disease":"Cold"}, 
{$set:{lastName:"Yuvi","age":28,"history.disease":["Fever","Ulergy"]}} 
)`

**Can someone please tell me how to update only Cold into Fever?**

Comment: Could you try `db.patient.updateOne({firstName:"Thanga","history.disease":"Cold"}, 
{$set:{lastName:"Yuvi","age":28,"history.disease.$":"Fever"}})` ?

Comment: @mickl thank you so much!! it is working perfectly

Comment: Will post it as an answer, maybe it will help someone

Answer (score 1):

> try this

```
db.patient.update(
  {
    "firstName":"Thanga",
    "history.disease":"Cold"
  }, 
  {
    $set:{
      "lastName":"Yuvi",
      "age":28,
      "history.disease.0":"Fever"
   }
  })
```